# Web.py todo list example but with database in memory

Tags: python, web.py

First of all I must say I am a complete newbie to `web.py`.

I want to modify the [todo list example](http://webpy.org/src/todo-list/0.3) to use a database in memory instead of using mysql.
I ended up writing:

```
import web

db = web.database(dbn="sqlite", db=":memory:")

db.query("CREATE TABLE todo (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT, title TEXT);")



def get_todos():

    return db.select('todo', order='id')

def new_todo(text):

    db.insert('todo', title=text)

def del_todo(id):

    db.delete('todo', where="id=$id", vars=locals())
```

But when I open the website I get:

```
<class 'sqlite3.OperationalError'> at /
no such table: todo
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it won't work by design, because webpy rerun all the program for each http request. So after at the second request, another database will be created so no persistence betwwen http requests.